# Java netbeans Arctan wrong answer?

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

I tried using both but its giving me wrong answers, according to my calculator the answer should be:

```
arctan(0.35) = 19.29
```

What I used:

```
Math.atan(Math.toRadians(angle)) and Math.atan();
```

Answer (score 7):

Your result is in degrees, not radians.

```
Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(0.35))
```

returns

```
19.290046219188735
```

which is your "expected" value. Make sure your inputs and outputs are in the correct unit!

Answer (score 0):

The methdo `Math.atan()` returns a result in radians:

> Returns the arc tangent of a value; the returned angle is in the range -pi/2 through pi/2. Special cases:
>
> If the argument is NaN, then the result is NaN.
>   If the argument is zero, then the result is a zero with the same sign as  the argument.
>   The computed result must be within 1 ulp of the exact result. Results must be semi-monotonic.

To obtain the value in degrees just perform a transformation:

```
@Test
public void arctan() {

    double result = Math.atan(0.35);

    assertThat(result*180/Math.PI).isBetween(19.29, 19.2901);
}
```